# How to change the libstreaming's videosource?

Tags: android, libstreaming

Everybody,I'm a young android developer,and now I have a requirement which is push my android phone's screen to my PC by rtsp.
Now I have start my project base on libstreaming. But I found it's videosource must be camera.So how to change it?

this is the part that set the MediaRecorder's params

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try with following code

```
mMediaRecord.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
```

but you need to use Camera2, and API level need more than 21.